# Greatest common divisor sequence

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, number-theory

Is there a common formula for this sequence?

```
gcd(1,n) * gcd(2,n) * ... * gcd(m,n)
```

for two positive integers `n`,`m`?

Comment: I've made an OEIS sequence that enumerates this for n, m > 0: https://oeis.org/A276162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can look at the slightly simpler problem of `gcd(1,n)*gcd(2,n)*....*gcd(n-1,n)`. Which is the sequence

`1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 12, 1, 16, 9, 80, 1, 3456, 1, 448, 2025, 2048, 1, 186624, 1,`

This has an entry in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences at [OEIS A051190](https://oeis.org/A051190). I can't see any particularly simple formula for this listed but the related sequence [OEIS A092287](https://oeis.org/A092287) can be considered a generation of factorials.

There is one obvious simplification of your problem. If `m < n` and n is prime then the result must be 1.